# Widget not appearing after being installed

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying a battery widget but it does not appear after getting installed.
I tried all the solutions mentioned in other posts for this problem. I added dummy activity in the manifest. Though, the activity is launched but widget is not shown. Do I have to link it somewhere other than what has been told?

Here is my manifest:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.batteryapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".androidmain"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="BatteryWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appWidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/battery_widget_info" >
            </meta-data>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the dummy class.
    package com.example.batteryapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class androidmain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));

        this.finish();
        //setContentView(R.layout.battery_widget);

    }

}
```

//Here is the .java class

```
package com.example.batteryapp;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class BatteryWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private final int BATTERY_STEPS=10;

    private RemoteViews widgetViews=new RemoteViews("com.example.batteryapp",R.layout.battery_widget);

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int []appWidgetIds){

        //register for the receiver when the battery changes
        Intent received=context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

        String receivedAction=received.getAction();
        if(receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){

            //get the level amount,pass default value
            int level=received.getIntExtra("level", 0);

            //indicate the level amount within the text view
            this.widgetViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_level, level+"%");

            Log.d("onUpdate_BW1","Before showBars()");
            //call helper to show the level bars
            showBars(level);
            Log.d("onUpdate_BW2","After showBars()");

            ComponentName appComponent=new ComponentName(context,BatteryWidget.class);

            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appComponent,this.widgetViews);
        }
    }   
        private void showBars(int currLevel){

            if(currLevel>=10){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar1, R.drawable.level_shape_low);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar1,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar1, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=20){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar2,R.drawable.level_shape_low);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar2, View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar2, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=30){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar3,R.drawable.level_shape_low);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar3,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar3, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=40){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar4,R.drawable.level_shape_mid);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar4,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar4, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=50){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar5,R.drawable.level_shape_mid);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar5,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar5, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=60){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar6,R.drawable.level_shape_mid);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar6,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar6, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=70){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar7,R.drawable.level_shape_high);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar7,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar7, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=80){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar8,R.drawable.level_shape_high);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar8,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar8, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=90){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar9,R.drawable.level_shape_high);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar9,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar9, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if(currLevel>=100){
                this.widgetViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.bar10,R.drawable.level_shape_high);
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar10,View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                this.widgetViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.bar10, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

}
```

//layout/battery_widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/battery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_level"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/level" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/top_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/bar9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

//xml/battery_widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/battery_widget"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

The activity is just launched but widget does not in my case.

Comment: I can't tell why your widget isn't working if there isn't any code showing how you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

The first read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Also I can not see any records about widget in manifest.

Comment: @Andrew Cumming: I am sorry for this. I have now edited my post and added complete code. Please have a look.

Comment: 1. View in layout is not obviously supported

Comment: I am not sure you can use it.
2. " <receiver android:name="BatteryWidget"" - show full path to class with package in manifest

Comment: here my piece of manifest 
<receiver  android:name="com.myproject.widgets.WidgetAppWidgetProvider"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="false" >
     <intent-filter >
        <action 
android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/app_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

Comment: Remove activity, it just prevents.
Make onUpdate as simple as you can, then when widget will work, add needed functionality.